# The type or namespace name 'GetAdminMasterPage' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been testing the example code here http://mywsat.codeplex.com/ and trying to move the project into an existing project I've already built.

I've copied all of the files and folders into my project but I get the following error repeated many times for all pages containing  `: GetAdminMasterPage`

`The type or namespace name 'GetAdminMasterPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

The example code behind in one of the pages is

```
using System;

public partial class admin_admin_edit_css : GetAdminMasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Which I assume means the `GetAdminMasterPage` is inherited? All of the folders and classes have been copied across and the `GetAdminMasterPage.cs` is located in App_Code/class/GetAdminMasterPage.cs. The code above is exactly the same as in MyWSAT which doesn't give an error.

I've also copied the Web.config file across which hasn't fixed the error.

Please can you advise on how to fix this?

UPDATE:

If I copy all of the files, then  include in project all works okay. As soon as I select the folders/files and select "Include in Project" I get the error.

Image1: Files copied, Show All Files - builds and runs without error
[image]

Image2: Files copied, Show All Files, Include in Project - gives error `the type or namespace name 'GetAdminMasterPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have copied that's ok, but still you have to include the namespace in this file for `GetAdminMasterPage` class.. See in which namespace it is defined and then include it after

```
using System;
//using GetAdminMasterPage - class namespace
```

Its correct that its there in `App_Code/class/GetAdminMasterPage.cs`, but see the namespace under which it is defined

Comment: There is no namespace in App_Code/class/GetAdminMasterPage.cs? That's what's confusing me

Comment: Have you included those files in your project using Visual studio? Are these files actually there in your project? (not just in your project derectory)..

Comment: Yes all files and folders have been copied. I copied and pasted the files between folders then in VS, show all files. I then went through every file and folder, right clicked Include in project.